# How should I structure my nested data Firestore

Tags: database, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, nested, nosql

I have a deeply nested structure for a Grades App I for which I want to use Firestore as my db. The nested structure is like this:

```
--Grades 
  |
   --Semesters
     |
      --Subjects
        |
         --Grade
```

Each of the types consists of metadata like name and id, and a list of the child type. For Example Semester has the fields: `String name, String id, List<Subjects>`

The idea is that the user can create subject and grades.

Each datatype has its own screen which shows the metadata and the list of its children. Therefore it should be possible to efficiently get the datatype and its children.

What would be the most nosql/firestore way to store this nested structure?

Comment: There are many approaches on how to structure data and it will depend on your use case. For more information, check these documentations [Structuring data](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/concepts/structure-data), [Structuring Data in Firestore](https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/react-part-time-react-track/react-with-nosql-part-1/structuring-data-in-firestore), [NoSQL Database](https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/nosql-modeling-database-structuring-part-ii-4c364c4bc17a)